# How to redirect the output of a script to a file, but not the error?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to append the output of wpa_passphrase to a file if the parameters are valid, and leave the err msg to the screen otherwise.

I use

```
wpa_passphrase 1 111 2>&1 >>file
wpa_passphrase 1 111111111 2>&1 >>file
```

but the file still contains the msg and screen did not:

```
Passphrase must be 8..63 characters
```

thanks to you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `wpa_passphrase` writes errors to *stdout* not to *stderr*. This code should solve the problem:

```
out=$(wpa_passphrase 1 1111111111) && echo "$out" >> file || echo "$out"
```

The code assigns the output to a variable and echos the variable to the file only if the preceding command is successful, otherwise it prints output to screen.

Comment: just wondering what the $ () does arround the wpa_passphrase command. thanks